# Neo4j: Expres path cypher query result in terms of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, recursive-query

I have the following node structure `Emp[e_id, e_name, e_bossid]`. What is more I have a **recursive query** that exploit the database in recursive traversal on SELF relation `e_bossid-[REPORTS_TO]->e_id`

```
MATCH (e:Employee) WHERE NOT (e)-[:REPORTS_TO]->()
SET e:Root;

MATCH path = (b:Root)<-[:REPORTS_TO*]-(e:Employee)
RETURN path
limit 1000;
```

However the result is PATH. I would like to have result in form of NODES not the path. I tried to use the `nodes(path)`, but it gives me an error:

`org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Reference node not available (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->java.util.HashMap["rel"]->java.util.HashMap["nodes(path)"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.entity.RestNode["restApi"]->org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIFacade["direct"]->org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI["referenceNode"])`

When I query without `nodes(path)` it seems to return only paths.

**How this should be done on the ground of cypher query?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to get all possible paths in your organizational hierarchy. Maybe what you want to get is a set of paths from the leaves of the tree to the root of the tree, and to return each unique set as a row of nodes.

```
MATCH (b:Employee)
WHERE NOT (b)-[:REPORTS_TO]->()
MATCH (l:Employee)
WHERE NOT (l)<-[:REPORTS_TO]-()
MATCH p = shortestPath((b)<-[:REPORTS_TO*]-(l))
RETURN nodes(p) as reports
```

As far as your error goes, that looks like a bug, although I don't know what version of Neo4j you are using. In all likelihood, your query won't complete because your `Root` employees are still a member of the `Employee` label. Which means that this pattern: `MATCH path = (b:Root)<-[:REPORTS_TO*]-(e:Employee)` matches the `Root` employees on each side of the variable length traversal.

Give my query a try and let me know what happens.